# Sending a details request to Google Places API - (CORS error)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reactjs, cors, google-places-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm trying to augment the collection of photos I have for public artworks in this project I'm working on with photos from the Google Places API. It says [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) that you can send a details request to get an array of ten photos. Eventually I will unpack the response to get Google's [photo reference](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) for each photo and make requests for each photo in the array and display it.

Unfortunately, this plan breaks when I send my details request. This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ5zf5lfXKRIYR8rPafbwaL68&key=MY_API_KEY. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4040' is therefore not allowed access. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I'm running this from my localhost and I'm pretty sure that matters. All of my other API calls (Google Maps API and a couple others) are written exactly as this is, so I'm a little confused why I'm getting the error. Here is the relevant code:

```
The actual API call:

export function getPhotos(placeID) {
  let obj = {
    method: 'GET'
  };
  return fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=' + placeID + '&key=MY_API_KEY')
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 400){
        throw new Error("Error getting photos for placeID: " + placeID)
      }
      return response.json()
    })
}
```

Let me know if you need any other information, I'd be happy to provide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [server side proxy](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/) to prevent this error. It works when you access the url directly because you have no origin when you do that.

- **JS AJAX request to local server -> remote server, request received, response sent, remote server -> local server -> AJAX request to JS.**

Check this related SO question:

- [What to do when an API doesn't allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946513/what-to-do-when-an-api-doesnt-allow-access-control-allow-origin)
- [webpack dev server CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602697/webpack-dev-server-cors-issue)

> You can either modify your API server so that [CORS is enabled](http://enable-cors.org/), or follow the [instructions on the webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server) page under "Combining with an existing server" to combine asset serving with webpack-dev-server and your own API server.

- [How do I make a CORS request with fetch on my localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367692/how-do-i-make-a-cors-request-with-fetch-on-my-localhost)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553720/1202830) suggests using a server-side proxy. While that is a good solution for the general case of accessing a web API that does not support CORS or JSONP, it's not the best solution for this specific problem.

Instead, use Google's [JavaScript Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) which is designed specifically for this kind of use. The links at the top of that page provide additional samples, guides, and reference material.

Comment: I still get cors errors even when using the places library on localhost.

Comment: This was really helpful. I got a direction.Either I can create a NodeJS server and request the Places API and send the response from nodeJS to my frontend app or use Place library in my frontend app. I still didn't solve the issue rather working on this. But after seeing this answer, I found in the Google places API documentation at the top it is clearly written that to develop a client side application one must use the JavaScript places library than  places API.

Answer (score 0):

I raised a similar question which got closed:-

[React - development server,"cors" issues using https url to retrieve data from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002928/react-development-server-cors-issues-using-https-url-to-retrieve-data-from-a)

I had the exact same issue using the google api from my localhost. After a painful day of trying various things the solution was incredibly simple.

I added the Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin chrome extension, whitelisted the api and turned CORs on.
This is a very old question and the solution might not have been viable at the time but I hope it helps someone some day!

Comment: we can not keep adding extensions for something to work on a browser. How will an end user know about an extension to make your web page work?

Comment: @naveenraina I believe he only brought that as a solution for testing on localhost, not for production