# Vue, Axios and Google Maps Place API CORS error

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, axios, cors

I've looked at the other answers, but unless I'm not getting the answer, they don't answer my question.

#### Environment

NodeJS **12.19.0**
VueJS **2.6.10**
Axios **0.15.3**

Current config for Axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = store.apiKey
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.common.crossDomain = true
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/*'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, */*'
```

I've tried this as well:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*, https://maps.googleapis.com/'
```

My Axios call (*from method section in a mixin*):

```
...
        loadPoi (lat, lng, radius = null, type = null) {
    
          if (!lat || !lng) {
            this.$message({message: 'Unable to load Places of Interest: invalid lat or lng values',
              type: 'warning'
            })
            return
          }
    
          let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + lat + ',' + lng + (radius ? '&radius=' + radius : '') + (type ? '&type=' + type : '') + '&key=' + GOOGLE_API_KEY
    
          console.log('loadPoi', url)
    /*
          var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
          xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false)  // false for synchronous request
          xmlHttp.send(null)
          console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)
    */
          axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.places = response.results
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.$message({message: 'Unable to load Places of Interest [' + e + ']',
              type: 'error'
            })
          })
        },
...
```

As you can see, even tried **raw** JavaScript call, same result.

The same URL works perfectly fine in the browser.

However when I access it from Axios, I get this error:

[image]
The raw header response:

```
GET /maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=2.0978,103.6063&radius=5000&key=[KEY] undefined
Host: maps.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,es-MX;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: undefined

crossDomain: true
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647369/google-places-api-cors-error If it is, why?

Answer (score -1):

Axios use for sent HTTP request, set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on a request is meaningless.

> In response, the **server** sends back an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin
> header** with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, which means that the
> resource can be accessed by any origin.
> [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

So, to allow CORS, the server-side need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * within its HTTP response.

But, it seems the response is from google API in your case, I think such service should already allow cross-origin access, could you please produce detailed error output?