# Google apis nearby search cant fetch json data into react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, google-nearby

What im trying to do is show the name of the first nearby place from a coordinate inside a div. It just doesn't show.

This is my code that fetches json

```
  const [business1, setbusiness1] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8943,151.2330&radius=1000&type=restaurant&keyword=attractions&key=MyApiKey&maxprice=1000')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => 
          {
            setbusiness1(data.results[0].name)
            console.log("data", data.results)
          });
  }, []);
```

This is my code that should display the name of the first attraction

```
  <div className="DetailedDescriptionsHalfLeft">
    agenda planner will be here 
    {business1} asfasfa

  </div>
```

The result is that it doesn't output anything in the div.

I checked the console output and this is the error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8943,151.2330&radius=1000&type=restaurant&keyword=attractions&key=MYApiKey&maxprice=1000. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Comment: Are you sure that data.results[0] has the value you are expecting?

Comment: yes im sure, I checked it in this website. 
https://www.jsonquerytool.com/

This is the json file:
https://pastebin.com/C3pE3Sy1

Comment: It just doesnt output anything for some reason. Is there something wrong with my API call?

Comment: Did you checked inside the fetch then block?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Add a console.log(data.results) before calling  setbusiness1

Comment: Ill try to do that

Comment: Yes, also you can add some text before console.log("data", data.results) and check your browser console if data is printed. If data is not printed then probably your fetch request is failing, so check the network tab in your browser

Comment: I have gotten this error in console

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8943,151.2330&radius=1000&type=restaurant&keyword=attractions&key=MYApiKey&maxprice=1000. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: Maybe here you can find an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542306/sending-a-details-request-to-google-places-api-cors-error

Comment: Im using Replit right now and im not sure how to use that answer in replit

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use async().
Here is a good exemple of how to do it.

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: Whats the difference between async and fetch? Could you help me out in how to write this with propper syntax?

Comment: Fetch() will get the data, while async() will await until the data are there. Please read the page on the link I put on my answer

Comment: @KMAHY the fetch request is OK, there is nothing wrong to use then block

Comment: The fetch request is OK but it does not wait for the response and start to render the html. It needs to await for the response and then display the html. Read the doc.