# CORS Error, Allow Origin from Google Developer Console Google Place API

Tags: reactjs, cors, google-places-api, fetch-api

I am using Place API from google, But getting error CORS

I am using fetch javascript API
React JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a details request to Google Places API - (CORS error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542306/sending-a-details-request-to-google-places-api-cors-error)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a duplicate question and you can find complete answers in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542306/sending-a-details-request-to-google-places-api-cors-error)

also, you can read about cors error [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), in a simple explanation, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources.

Basically, this is a configuration to web server API and you should fix the problem there, but there is something you can try out for the front-end development local environment you can use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) if you are using chrome and [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) for firefox, they simply add some headers to requests and responses to pass cors error. there are some other solutions to this you can find in the post I mentioned above